# OpenCV - how to remove blurring effect in final fused result obtained using laplacian pyramidal fusion

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am trying to implement laplacian pyramidal fusion algorithm in OpenCV to perform image fusion. In the algorithm, we first construct Gaussian pyramid by downsampling them. Then we construct Laplacian Pyramid using those downsampled images. After that while fusion, we upsample them to get the final fused image. My doubt is regarding the fact that when we are downsampling the image we are losing the information of every alternate rows and column. And when we upsample the images back we get blurred effect (given in OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/pyramids/pyramids.html)) then how to implement this without getting the blurring effect

**This is the final fused image I am getting**

[image]

Comment: I guess you may use some other algorithm to fuse the images, Can you attach the sample images ?

Comment: @ZdaR I have attached the final fused image. I don't have enough reputation points to provide more than one link.  The two images that I am trying to fuse are the same and have different contrasts. The final goal is to have an image which is better than the two input images. The problem is the white spots in the image (like the one that can be observed on the sofa) and the blurring of edges of objects in the image (like the edges of lamp in the back).

Comment: @ZdaR can u suggest other algorithms that can be used to fuse the images

Comment: And what is the expected output ?

Comment: I have two images of different contrast taken during low light conditions. The final image should have the best contrast and brightness among all the input images. <www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ronrubin/Projects/fusion/>